VBA WinHttp Request to TrackingMore API Returning Empty Data
I am trying to use VBA to get tracking information from the TrackingMore API. I am using the WinHttpRequest object in VBA. My API calls seem to be successful as I get a response with a status code of 200, but the data array in the response is empty. Here is my code:
Sub GetTrackingInfo_2()
    
    Dim http As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim apiKey As String
    Dim carrierCodes As Variant
    Dim trackingNumbers As Variant
    Dim response As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim json As Object

    apiKey = "" 'Please use your key if possible
    carrierCodes = Array("bluedart", "delhivery", "dtdc", "bluedart")
    

    trackingNumbers = Array("78051987016", "21025821925200", "I45618896", "80545687143")
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    For i = LBound(carrierCodes) To UBound(carrierCodes)
        url = "https://api.trackingmore.com/v4/trackings/" & carrierCodes(i) & "/" & trackingNumbers(i)
        
        With http
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "Tracking-Api-Key", apiKey
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
            .send
            response = .responseText
        End With
        
        Debug.Print response
        
    Next i

    Set http = Nothing
    
End Sub

I am getting the following response for each request:
{"meta":{"code":200,"type":"Success","message":"The request was successful."},"data":[]}
{"meta":{"code":200,"type":"Success","message":"The request was successful."},"data":[]}
{"meta":{"code":200,"type":"Success","message":"The request was successful."},"data":[]}
{"meta":{"code":200,"type":"Success","message":"The request was successful."},"data":[]}

Steps already Taken:

Verified that the API key is correct.
Checked that the carrier codes and tracking numbers are valid and correctly formatted.
Ensured the Content-Type and Tracking-Api-Key headers are set correctly.

Questions:
Why is the data array in the response always empty despite the successful request?

What do you get when querying https://api.trackingmore.com/v4/trackings/get directly?

since no authentication therefore getting: 401 "Authentication failed or has no permission. Please check and ensure your API Key is correct." data=null

I didn't mean to remove the authentication, I just meant to query the main URL directly without carrier code and tracking number.

Based on the TrackingMore documentation, you need to pass the carrier/courier number and the tracking number as URL parameters instead of including them in the URL path.
CURL equivalence:

curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.trackingmore.com/v4/trackings/get?tracking_numbers=123&courier_code=123' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Tracking-Api-Key: 123'


In VBA, you'd need to replace the line where you define the URL with something like this:

url = "https://api.trackingmore.com/v4/trackings/get?courier_code=" & carrierCodes(i) & "&tracking_numbers=" & trackingNumbers(i)



@VBAbyMBA Did you get a chance to try this?
